# My function in typescript/react is not assignable to img src attribute in JSX. Possible work around?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Hello new to Typescript in React. I have a function "logoSwitcher" that returns a string (imported URL), based on the state of "theme.mode"**

```
import logoDark from "./images/JW-logo.png";
import logo from "./images/Weisberglogo.svg";
import { useTheme } from "./ThemeManager";

function Header() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const logoSwitcher = (): string => {
    if (theme.mode === "light") {
      return logo || "";
    } else {
      return logoDark || "";
    }
  };

 return (
    <div className="header__container">
      <img src={logoSwitcher} className="header__logo" alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Im getting red squiggles under the img > src attribute and the following error:**

Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Header.tsx(22, 16): Did you mean to call this expression? Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Header.tsx(22, 16): Did you mean to call this expression?

I am unclear why the src attribute will not accept this function that clearly returns a string. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Because you're passing a function reference, not a string.

Comment: logoSwitcher is a function. Not a.string. so you should call it.  `src={logoSwitcher()}`

Comment: Ah that makes sense thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the @Jerome said you need to call the function to get the value like this

```
import logoDark from "./images/JW-logo.png";
import logo from "./images/Weisberglogo.svg";
import { useTheme } from "./ThemeManager";

function Header() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const logoSwitcher = (): string => {
    if (theme.mode === "light") {
      return logo || "";
    } else {
      return logoDark || "";
    }
  };

 return (
    <div className="header__container">
      <img src={logoSwitcher()} className="header__logo" alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```